# Encoding with unicode and non unicode characters in HTML

Tags: python, html, unicode, unicode-string, python-unicode

I am using this package here: [HTML.py 0.04](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/HTML.py)

Here is what I am doing:

```
import html
h = html.HTML()
h.p('Some simple Euro: €1.14')
h.p(u'Some Euro: €1.14')
```

Now when I do `>>> unicode(h)` I get an error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)

What is the best way to handle this? 
I need to write the html to a file.

Comment: In Py2, at best, try to always use unicode strings (`u''`), you can use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of your file to automagically convert most of `''` to `u''` automatically. Personally, I'd avoid Py2 if possible, it is a mess about encoding (doing lot of conversion in your back) and can be very confusing easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
h.p('Some simple Euro: €1.14')
```

You should avoid byte strings (`''` in Python 2, `b''` in Python 3) for HTML content. The character model of HTML is Unicode, so only Unicode strings (`u''`) should be used.

You can get away with doing it wrong for simple ASCII characters. Because most common byte encodings are supersets of ASCII, Python 2 will implicitly convert ASCII byte strings to Unicode. But the `€` character isn't part of ASCII, so Python can't tell how to read it. If you have saved the source code above using the UTF-8 encoding then you have the byte string `b'\xe2\x82\xac'`, which could mean `€`, `â‚¬`, `竄ｬ`, or many other character sequences depending on what encoding is used.